# What is known about partial sums involving squares of the totient function?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

The behaviour of the sum:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$

is well-studied. However, I am interested in the behaviour of the following sum, and haven't been able to find any material about it online:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \Big( \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} \Big)^2$$

Alternatively, it seems like this sum can be expressed in the form:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \displaystyle\sum_{d|n, \ e|n} \frac{\mu(e) \mu(d)}{de}$$

Is anything known about the behaviour of this partial sum?

**Note:** I would really appreciate if anyone answering this question didn't give me an outright answer, maybe just a small hint to point me in the right direction, as I'd **really** like to figure this out myself. Thank you!

Comment: lots of books on analytic number theory. I've got Apostol around here somewhere, title Introduction to Analytic Number Theory. Hardy and Wright do some bits. Note that the one mathematics book I saw computer science professors generally had on office bookshelf was Hardy and Wright.

Comment: I have Apostol sitting beside me right now, and I haven't been able to find anything about this sum. Perhaps I haven't looked hard enough, I'll page through it again. Thanks!

Comment: There may be no explicit mention of your partial sum, but lots of methods you can learn

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: Found my copy. I have the first(1976) edition, in case you have a different edition. The partial sums of $\phi(n) / n^\alpha$ are done in exercises 6,7,8, with $\alpha = 2$ in ex. 6 on page 71, end of chapter 3.  Your sums should be related as far as initial setup.  Alright, $\alpha = 1$ is page 70 just before, exercises 4 and 5 and the final comment for ex. 5 gives $\frac{x}{\zeta (2)} + O(\log x) $ for sum of $\phi(n) / n$

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help

Comment: For multiplicative $f$, it often works to write $f = g \ast h$, with $g$ a simple multiplicative function that is "close" to $f$, and $h$ then being "small". Here, $\bigl(\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\bigr)^2$ is close to $1$ for $n$ a prime power, so taking $g \colon n \mapsto 1$ and consequently $$h(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)\cdot \biggl(\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}\biggr)^2$$ offers itself. That works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure I totally understand: are you saying the sum becomes simpler when $f$ is written in this form? I tried writing it out and it didn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It becomes simpler in the sense that it leads to a form from which the asymptotic $C\cdot x + O(\log^2 x)$ is easily obtainable. But as far as I know, the constant $C$ has no simple expression in terms of familiar constants. However, with a few tricks it is not too hard to compute it to a reasonable precision. On another note, if you reply to a comment, please use `@username` to have the recipient be notified of your reply.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @DanielFischer!

Comment: @DanielFischer I just posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974242/a-sum-involving-the-mobius-function-and-a-product-over-prime-factors Your method worked very well, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding a good approximation for the $C$ that you mention!