# A sum involving the Mobius function and a product over prime factors

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

This is a follow-up question to: [What is known about partial sums involving squares of the totient function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969144/what-is-known-about-partial-sums-involving-squares-of-the-totient-function)

Using the hint given by [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer), I was able to express the sum posed in the question in the following way:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{r \leq x} \Big( \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} \Big)^2 = x \displaystyle\sum_{r \leq x} \frac{\mu(r)}{r^2} \displaystyle\prod_{p | r} \Big(2 - \frac{1}{p} \Big) = x \displaystyle\sum_{r \leq x} \frac{\mu(r)}{r^2} \displaystyle\sum_{d | r} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} 2^{\omega(r/d)}$$

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of this sum, and unfortunately, I am stuck once again. Numerical experimentation suggests that:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{r \leq x} \Big( \frac{\varphi(r)}{r} \Big)^2 = \frac{6}{\sqrt{2} \pi^2} x + O(\text{something})$$

Interestingly enough, we know that:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

so I'm inclined to believe that the first sum separates nicely, when we split it into a sum from $1$ to $\infty$, minus the sum for all $r > x$.

I am only familiar with very basic analytic number theory, I don't know of any tricks to use to try to compute the product of primes in the first equation, or do something else that would allow for a clean solution. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\varphi(n)/n)^2 n^{-s}= F(s)\zeta(s)$$ where $$F(s)=\sum_{m\ge 1} a_m m^{-s}= \prod_p (1-p^{-s})(1+\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(p-1)^2}{p^2}p^{-sk})$$ $$= \prod_p (1+O(p^{-1})p^{-s}+\sum_{k\ge 2} O(1)p^{-2s})$$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s)>1/2$. Thus $$\sum_{n\le x} (\varphi(n)/n)^2 = \sum_{m\le 1} a_m \lfloor x/m\rfloor = x \sum_{m\le 1} a_m/m+ O(\sum_{m\le x} |a_m|)=xF(1)+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$$
I don't think
$$F(1)=\prod_p (1-p^{-1})(1+\frac{p-1}{p^2})$$ has a closed-form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way to approximate $F(1)$? It seems very likely, at least based on some experimentation, that it approaches $6/(\pi^2 \sqrt{2})$

Comment: It is a good approximation but not the exact value. Try this in https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html `N = 10^5;
f(p) = if(isprime(p),(1.0-1/p)*(1+1/p-1/p^2),1);
a=prod(p=2,N,f(p));
a-6.0/(Pi^2*sqrt(2)) `

Comment: Thanks! As suspected, it is close to $6/\pi^2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Very good! The product over all primes converges slowly, it would take forever to get a good approximation. I was thinking about a way to get more precise results, and discovered that GP *has* a function for that: `prodeulerrat((1-1/p)*(1+1/p-1/p^2),1)`. I couldn't find out details of the implementation, but my GP says it's about $0.42824950567709444021876570758182354612$. @Jack Ceroni Inverse symbolic calculators don't recognise this value, so there isn't a closed expression, most likely.

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorVector!

Comment: @Jack Ceroni  You're welcome. BTW, I've implemented my own ideas how to compute that product, and it coincides with the result of `prodeulerrat`, so I'd say we're on safe ground, there.

Comment: Amazing, thanks again for your help @ProfessorVector!